# Sorting in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column abc in table t1. The column has values

```
A1
A2   
A3
A4
.
.
A12
B1
B2
.
.
.
B12
C1
C2
.
.
.
C12
H1
.
.
H12
```

I wanna sort them such that the output is

```
A1
B1
C1
.
.
H1
A2
B2
C2
.
.
.
H2
.
.
.
.
A12
.
.
.
H12
```

A  `select *  from abc` statement gives A1,A10,A2.... as output. I am trying to use SUBSTR but haven't gotten it right.

Comment: Do you mean that the value in each row is a comma-delimited list?

Comment: Oh no. Its stored in a table abc. 1 row per value

Comment: Stil ur input data is not clear..

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem is you want the numeric part of the value to be sorted *ordinally* (A1, B1, A2, B2, A10...) instead of alphabetically (A1, A10, A2, B1, B2...), correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it;

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(VALUE, 2) + 0, 
         SUBSTRING(VALUE, 1, 1);
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f26fc/1).

Comment: I really like that solution. But is the second call to `SUBSTRING` really necessary? Wouldn't just using `VALUE` as the second sort be sufficient?

Comment: @bfavaretto Yes, you're right, the second substring could be replaced by just `VALUE` without any ill effects.

Comment: @Ankur It converts the string to an integer before sorting so that the sort is numeric instead of a string sort. Otherwise `10` will sort before `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the format is always a single alpha char followed by any number of digits:

```
ORDER BY RIGHT(colname, LENGTH(colname)-1)
```

Comment: Well LENGth(colname-1) will not take care of any number of digits.

Comment: If I have A12 length(colname) - 1 will give character '1' and If I have A2, Length(colname)-1 will give 'A'

Comment: @bfavaretto Since you're doing a string sort, `12` will be sorted before `2`.

Comment: @Ankur, `LENGTH` just returns the string length. So if I have A12345, it returns 6. So `RIGHT('A12345', LENGTH('A12345')-1)` is the same AS `RIGHT('A12345', 5)`, which are the 5 rightmost characters, `12345`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, AFAIK MySQL does not allows explicitly casting to `INT`, so I was assuming it would cast it automatically. Are you sure it would do string sort in this case? I didn't test...

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:

```
ORDER BY LEFT(colname,1), RIGHT(colname, LENGTH(colname)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
order by lpad(date_created,1,0) ASC
```

@bfavaretto i think if you use -1 in length colname, and you have 3 characters like in example you will have some strange results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Square
FROM    Table1
ORDER   BY         
        CASE WHEN Square REGEXP '^[A-Z]{2}'
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END ASC,
        CASE WHEN Square REGEXP '^[A-Z]{2}'
            THEN LEFT(Square, 2)
            ELSE LEFT(Square, 1)
        END ASC,
        CASE WHEN Square REGEXP '^[A-Z]{2}'
            THEN CAST(RIGHT(Square, LENGTH(Square) - 2) AS SIGNED)
            ELSE CAST(RIGHT(Square, LENGTH(Square) - 1) AS SIGNED)
        END ASC
```